# Class doesn't define properly. Needs identifier

Tags: c++, class

so I've just tried my hand with classes in c++. They seemed straightforward enough, until i tried defining one for use in a vector.

Then all of the sudden it doesn't work. Class is:

```
class throw{
    public:
    string thrower;
    int longit;
    int latit;
};
```

which is exactly how the tutorial told me to do it, but it keeps returning:
"error: expected identifier before 'throw'"

Comment: `throw` is a reserved keyword in C++... You can not name a class `throw`. What tutorial do you rever to?

Comment: thank you, coding without an IDE is hard :/ w3schools and geekforgeeks

Comment: It would be a good idea to download an IDE, or at least use an online one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either tutorial is wrong and you'd better find a better one or you need to rename your class to `Throw`, because ***C++ is case sensitive***, and `throw` is a reserved keyword.